# Evaluate statements from within Python logging YAML config file

Tags: python, logging, yaml

Consider the following snippet of a Python `logging` YAML config file:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  logfile:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    filename: some_fancy_import_name.generate_filename_called_error
    backupCount: 5
    formatter: simple
```

I would like to load this YAML config file this way:

```
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as fd:
    config = yaml.safe_load(fd.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Take special notice of the `filename` to which the `handler` should write logs.  In normal Python code, I would expect `some_fancy_import_name.generate_filename_called_errorlog` to generate the string `'error.log'`.  All in all, I would like to say that this logging handler should write to the file `'error.log'` in the current directory.

However, as it turns out, this is not the case.  When I look at the current directory, I see a file named `'some_fancy_import_name.generate_filename_called_errorlog'`.

#### Why go through all this trouble?

I would like `filename` to be programmatically determined.  I have successfully tried configuring logging using normal Python scripting this way:

```
# fancy import name
from os import environ as env

# Programmatically determine filename path
log_location = env.get('OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR', '.')
log_filename = os.path.join(log_location, 'error')
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_filename)
```

See how the `log_filename` path was inferred from environment variables.

I would like to translate this to a YAML config file.  Is it possible?

Perhaps I might need to dig through the `dict` produced by `yaml.safe_load(fd.read())` and do some `eval()` stuff?

Comment: Don't answer the question in the question itself. Either accept flyx's answer, or post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom constructor and mark the value with a special tag, so your constructor gets executed when loading it:

```
import yaml

def eval_constructor(loader, node):
  return eval(loader.construct_scalar(node))

yaml.add_constructor(u'!eval', eval_constructor)

some_value = '123'

config = yaml.load("""
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  logfile:
    class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    filename: !eval some_value
    backupCount: 5
    formatter: simple
""")

print config['handlers']['logfile']['filename']
```

This prints `123`, since the value `some_value` has the tag `!eval`, and therefore is loaded with `eval_constructor`.

**Be aware of the security implications of `eval`ing configuration data. Arbitrary Python code can be executed by writing it into the YAML file!**

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Thanks to [flyx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574366/366309), this is how I did it:

```
import logging
import yaml
from os import environ as env

def constructor_logfilename(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return os.path.join(env.get('OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR', '.'), value)

yaml.add_constructor(u'!logfilename', constructor_logfilename)
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as fd:
    config = yaml.load(fd.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

In the `logging.yaml` file, here's the important snippet:

```
...
filename: !logfilename error.log
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just now had this issue come up myself and I approached it in a much more boring way. I left out the filename attribute of the logfile handler from my yaml file and added it to the config dictionary created by yaml.load like this:

```
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as fd:
    config = yaml.load(fd.read())
config['handlers']['logfile']['filename'] = generate_logfile_name(...)
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```