# How to reference an existing variable in YAML?

Tags: python, yaml

Let's say I have an object already defined in my Python script that serves as a container for some random items.  Each attribute of the container corresponds to an item.  In this simple example, I have an `ITEMS` object that has a `BALL` attribute which points to a `Ball` instance.

Now, I need to load some content in YAML, but I want that content to be able to reference the existing `ITEMS` variable that is already defined.  Is this possible?  Maybe something along the lines of...

```
ITEMS = Items()
setattr(Items, 'BALL', Ball())

yaml_text = "item1: !!python/object:ITEMS.BALL"
yaml_items = yaml.load(yaml_text)
```

My goal, after loading the YAML, is for `yaml_items['item1']` to be the `Ball` instance from the `ITEMS` object.

Comment: What third-party YAML library/module are you using? It's unlikely you'll be able to easily do this unless it's a feature of whatever that is.

Comment: @martineau I've been trying out both PyYAML and ruamel.yaml with simple things, but the module we go with is still TBD.

Comment: I was just looking at the [description](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML/3.12) of the PyYAML module and it says "PyYAML features a complete YAML 1.1 parser, Unicode support, pickle support, capable extension API, and sensible error messages. PyYAML supports standard YAML tags and **provides Python-specific tags that allow to represent an arbitrary Python object**." (emphasis mine), so it just sound like you just need to figure out how to do that last part—is there any documentation and have you read it?

Comment: @martineau I've looked through docs for [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and for [ruamel.yaml](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).  There are ways to use python-specific tags, like you mentioned, but I haven't seen anything for using an existing object like I initially proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it the uses the `di()` function defined in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012814/355230) to another question. It takes the integer value returned from the built-in `id()` function and converts it to a string. The `yaml.load()` function will call a custom constructor which then does the reverse of that process to determine the object returned.

**Caveat:** This takes advantage of the fact that, with CPython at least, the `id()` function returns the address of the Python object in memory—so it may not work with other implementations of the interpreter.

```
import _ctypes
import yaml

def di(obj_id):
    """ Reverse of id() function. """
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

def py_object_constructor(loader, node):
    return di(int(node.value))

yaml.add_constructor(u'!py_object', py_object_constructor)

class Items(object): pass

def Ball(): return 42

ITEMS = Items()
setattr(Items, 'BALL', Ball())  # Set attribute to result of calling Ball().

yaml_text = "item1: !py_object " + str(id(ITEMS.BALL))
yaml_items = yaml.load(yaml_text)

print(yaml_items['item1'])  # -> 42
```

If you're OK with using `eval()`, you could formalize this and make it easier to use by monkey-patching the `yaml` module's `load()` function to do some preprocessing of the yaml stream:

```
import _ctypes
import re
import yaml

#### Monkey-patch yaml module.
def _my_load(yaml_text, *args, **kwargs):
    REGEX = r'@@(.+)@@'

    match = re.search(REGEX, yaml_text)
    if match:
        obj = eval(match.group(1))
        yaml_text = re.sub(REGEX, str(id(obj)), yaml_text)

    return _yaml_load(yaml_text, *args, **kwargs)

_yaml_load = yaml.load  # Save original function.
yaml.load = _my_load  # Change it to custom version.
#### End monkey-patch yaml module.

def di(obj_id):
    """ Reverse of id() function. """
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

def py_object_constructor(loader, node):
    return di(int(node.value))

yaml.add_constructor(u'!py_object', py_object_constructor)

class Items(object): pass

def Ball(): return 42

ITEMS = Items()
setattr(Items, 'BALL', Ball())  # Set attribute to result of calling Ball().

yaml_text = "item1: !py_object @@ITEMS.BALL@@"
yaml_items = yaml.load(yaml_text)
print(yaml_items['item1'])  # -> 42
```

Comment: This is a very interesting and clever implementation, and I may end up giving this a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Also note that this doesn't use `eva()l`, so is more secure than what's in @flyx's answer. Doing something like this for JSON is better and easier to implement because the `json` module has a hook that allows something like the `+ str(id(ITEMS.BALL))` part to be done more automatically. I'm not that familiar with the `yaml` module—installed it just to test my answer—so there may be a better way to implement it than what is shown here.

Answer (score 0):

@martineau quoted the documentation:

> […] provides Python-specific tags that allow to represent an arbitrary Python object.

*represent*, not *construct*. It means that you can dump any Python object to YAML, but you can *not* reference an existing Python object inside YAML.

That being said, you can of course add your own constructor to do it:

```
import yaml

def eval_constructor(loader, node):
  return eval(loader.construct_scalar(node))

yaml.add_constructor(u'!eval', eval_constructor)

some_value = '123'

yaml_text = "item1: !eval some_value"
yaml_items = yaml.load(yaml_text)
```

**Be aware of the security implications of `eval`ing configuration data. Arbitrary Python code can be executed by writing it into the YAML file!**

<sub>Mostly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574366/347964)</sub>

Comment: Defining my own constructor is a strategy I've considered, but I was hoping to avoid this so that I wouldn't have to do any of my own text parsing or `eval`ing.  That being said, I appreciate the suggestion.  Thanks!